# Как можно сократить начальную переменную, при наборе кода в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, idle, turtle

На примере рабочего кода:

```
import turtle

pen = turtle.Turtle()
pen.forward(100)
pen.left(30)
pen.forward(100)
pen.right(60)
```

Возможно ли сократить первое слово `pen` чтобы постоянно его не писать?

Например так:

```
import turtle

pen = turtle.Turtle()

from pen import *

forward(100)
left(30)
forward(100)
right(60)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

К сожалению, аналога блока `with`, работающего в такой ситуации, найти не удалось. Однако часто используемые методы вы можете выносить в отдельные переменные

```
import turtle

pen = turtle.Turtle()

# вынесем методы в отдельные переменные. Они также могут называться right, left и forward, для сокращения назвал их r, l и f соответственно
r = pen.right
l = pen.left
f = pen.forward

f(100)
l(300)
f(100)
r(60)
```

[image]

Comment: А если таких методов множество? Замучаешься вытаскивать в переменные

Answer (score 0):

Например так, но может чтото сломать

```
globals().update(pen.__dict__)
```